# Trying to show a <tr> if an option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, sharepoint-2010

I've hidden a row in a form but I'd like this row to display when my select option is set to "Cancelled"

This is how I went about it:

```
if($("option[value='Cancelled']").attr("selected") == "selected"){
    //Remove New option when Cancelled
    $("option[value='New']").remove();
    $("nobr").filter(function () { return $.trim(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue) === "Cancel Note"; }).closest("tr").show();
}
```

In the console, I've noticed that the selected attribute does not dynamically change when switching between , I assume that's the problem but I'm not sure how to go about fixing that.

Rest of Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideFields");

//Disables unused Priority radiobox
function hideFields() {
    //priority - disable unchecked radiobox
    var reg = document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_0537f4e9_69aa_409a_b5ed_15e3624efeab_ctl00_ctl05_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00");
    var high = document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_0537f4e9_69aa_409a_b5ed_15e3624efeab_ctl00_ctl05_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl01");

    if(reg.checked == true){
        high.disabled=true;
    }else{
        reg.disabled=true;
    }
    //On item edit, set status to In Progress if in New
    if($("option[value='New']").attr("selected") == "selected"){
        //Disable New
        $("option[value='New']").remove();
        $("option[value='Completed']").remove();
        $("option[value='Cancelled']").remove();

        //Enable In Progress
        $("option[value='In Progress']").attr("selected","selected");

    }else if($("option[value='In Progress']").attr("selected") == "selected"){
        //Remove New option
        $("option[value='New']").remove();
        $("option[value='In Progress']").remove();
        $("option[value='Completed']").attr("selected","selected");
        $("nobr").filter(function () { return $.trim(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue) === "Cancel Note"; }).closest("tr").hide();
    }else if($("option[value='Completed']").attr("selected") == "selected" ){
        //Remove New option when Completed/Cancelled
        $("option[value='New']").remove();
        $("nobr").filter(function () { return $.trim(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue) === "Cancel Note"; }).closest("tr").hide();
    }else if($("option[value='Cancelled']").is(':selected')){
        //Remove New option when Cancelled
        $("option[value='New']").remove();
        $("nobr").filter(function () { return $.trim(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue) === "Cancel Note"; }).closest("tr").show();
}

    //call orderID
    orderID();
}
function PreSaveAction() {
    //Check is Work Order is claimed
    if ($('#content').length == 0){
    alert("Please claim Work Order by typing your name or email in NAPA User Field");
    return false ;
    }
    else { return true ;}
}

//I've deprecated this function - Not compatible with Chrome/FF
function findacontrol(FieldName) {
   var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("!");
   // get all comments
   for (var i=0;i < arr.length; i++ )
   {
      // now match the field name
      if (arr[i].innerHTML.indexOf(FieldName) > 0)
      {         return arr[i];      }
   }
}

//Sets Order ID field to read only in edit form
function orderID() {
    //Set the Field to Read only and change its background colour
    $("input[title='Order ID']").attr("readonly","true").css('background-color','#F6F6F6');

    //call setFocus();
    setFocus();
    }

//Sets cursor Focus to NAPA users
function setFocus() {
    //set focus to NAPA user
    document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_0537f4e9_69aa_409a_b5ed_15e3624efeab_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_UserField_upLevelDiv").focus();
}

 </script>
```

Comment: can you show your html related to this code

Comment: yup here is what I have http://i.imgur.com/sfZuKZP.png

Comment: what triggers this block of code?

Comment: I'll post the entire thing. It's triggered by load. I'm guessing I need something to trigger this block onchange or something like thaT?

Comment: Well it depends on when you want this to happen. Normally a check on the select value is done on change of the select - which is what I used in my example below.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what triggers your block of code, but just for testing purposes I'll use the change event on the select. This is how I would do it:

```
$("#myselect").on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() == "Cancelled") {
        //Remove New option when Cancelled
        $this.find("option[value='New']").remove();
        $("nobr").filter(function () {
            return $.trim(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue) === "Cancel Note";
        }).closest("tr").show();
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eYrAY/)

Comment: $("#ct100_DropDownChoice").on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() == "Cancelled") ... wouldn't the if statement here check if <select value="Cancelled">, but <select> doesn't have a value attribute.

Comment: @Batman The select's value is the value of the option that is currently showing within that select as demonstrated in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kp4Zz/

Comment: Hmm I tried it but it didn't work. Is there any chance the select tag would work differently in SharePoint. I've inspected the element and there is no value attribute in the select tag but the option does have a selected attribute.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference. If you could recreate your issue in a fiddle (pull only the code/dom that matters), that would be helpful.

Comment: It won't work, this is what I used: if($("option[value='Cancelled']").is(':selected')){
  //Remove New option when Cancelled
  $("option[value='New']").remove();
}
$("#ct100_DropDownChoice").on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() == "Cancelled") {
        //Remove New option when Cancelled
        $("nobr").filter(function () {
            return $.trim(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue) === "Cancel Note";
        }).closest("tr").show();
    }

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing there, you have some stuff at the beginning that is outside the change event. Then you have the change event minus the `$this.find("option[value='New']").remove();`

Comment: Are you wanting this stuff to happen when the `select` is changed or are you wanting it to happen based on the default selection when the page loads?

Comment: yea sorry, I took out the New option when the item is In Progress (users should be able to bring it back to new) so it didn't need to be in the change event. The only change I'm trying to accomplish is displaying the Cancellation Note box when the dropdown is set to Cancel. I tried adding the value attribute to the select tag manually to see if that would work but it doesn't change the text in the box. I'm not sure why not.

Comment: This same code is working fine in my jsfiddle. Maybe your selectors don't match your dom? Maybe you could just post a link at this point.

Comment: it's an intranet sharepoint portal, there's really no way for me to post to the link. I can try to provide more html is that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if($("option[value='Cancelled']").is(':selected')){
    //Remove New option when Cancelled
    $("option[value='New']").remove();
    $("nobr").filter(function () { return $.trim(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue) === "Cancel Note"; }).closest("tr").show();
}
```